# Can't get sIFR to display

Tags: sifr

I can't get sIFR to display. It just shows the regular web text. I've went through the steps several times.

Maybe I'm just missing some tiny bit of code, but I think I've followed all the steps correctly. Just can't get it to display.

Anyone want to look and see if I'm just screwing up some mundane detail? Here is a link to my test page

[Test Page](http://www.creativewhirlwind.com/reallynewversion/sifr_test/sifr_test.html)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're including the config file before the main library file. Try to switch it around.

If you're in Firefox, you can look at the Error Console. Where it says.

```
Error: sIFR is not defined
Source File: http://www.creativewhirlwind.com/reallynewversion/sifr_test/js/sifr-config.js
Line: 25
```

You should also look at using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I'll give that a try. Is that a pretty common mistake on this?

Comment: I don't know if this is a common error for sIFR but I know it happens a lot with javascript libraries with poor documentation.